# How to add asp.net mvc5 to visual studio express 2012 edition?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-5

I have visual studio 2012 express edition installed on my pc. I want to learn asp.net with mvc5. How can I add ASP.net with mvc5 to my vs2012 express edition? please help!

Comment: The express version is limited to the project types it supports, so it could be that you need the Web Express version as linked here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc5

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the directions in [Using ASP.NET MVC5 within Visual Studio 2012 - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/696518/Using-ASP-NET-MVC-within-Visual-Studio); it has you download an update for Visual Studio 2012. I'm not sure if it will work with express version or only the paid version.

Also, if you are a student you can sign up for [Microsoft DreamSpark](https://www.dreamspark.com/) which will give you a copy of Visual Studio for learning.